# How to run the script in anaconda3?

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I'am trying to run SimSwap script and use Anaconda3. I've created the enviroment with python 3.6, installed all the modules, all thigs as on github [SimSwap](https://github.com/neuralchen/SimSwap/blob/main/docs/guidance/preparation.md) page, and when I try to run this script:

```
python test_video_swapsingle.py --isTrain false  --name people --Arc_path arcface_model/arcface_checkpoint.tar --pic_a_path ./demo_file/demo_pic.jpg --video_path ./demo_file/demo_video.mp4 --output_path ./output/output_video.mp4 --temp_path ./temp_results
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_video_swapsingle.py", line 12, in <module>
from util.videoswap import video_swap
File "C:\SimSwap\SimSwap-main\util\videoswap.py", line 9, in <module>
import moviepy.editor as mp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy'
```

but when I do command pip list module moviepy is already installed. I think it's because I have already installed python 3.9 and when I try to run the script it's conflict between different python versions. Help me please to get rid of this error. Thanks.

[image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uld9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the case that `pip` is not installing to your anaconda environment. Try running `which pip` to see if you're using the pip inside your anaconda environment, if not you have to specify the full path to this pip.

An alternative is to install via Anaconda instead:

```
conda install -c conda-forge moviepy
```